# How to make VS uses Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I really don't like `cmd.exe` and when it is possible I use `Windows PowerShell`. When I run my console application from Visual Studio, it runs it in `cmd.exe`. Is it possible to make Visual Studio 13 use `Windows PowerShell` as the terminal emulator?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. When a console application (including `cmd.exe` AND `powershell.exe` !) is run in Windows (from Visual Studio or otherwise), a process called `conhost.exe` is created. Displaying the console window is its responsibility. No instance of `cmd.exe` itself is created unless specified in the project's properties under `Debug`, and even then this only happens when debugging.

Comment: @DoomMuffins I understand you, but I want to see blue window instead of black ;)

Comment: powershell isn't a special color. open a cmd.exe console and write powershell.

Comment: So my question is to how to do so Visual Studio invokes PowerShell.

Comment: You can set the colors from the console window system menu - if you set the defaults, they'll apply to just your exe (path based).

Comment: enedil, you can't. PowerShell isn't a console host, it's an application. A console host can only display one application at the same time. It can show powershell or your application, not both at the same time. If you only want the color scheme, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 DoomMuffins.

What you think is `cmd.exe` is actually `conhost.exe` (the black console window). This is the same console host that PowerShell uses, only with different colors.

Conhost is the visual console, and your application, powershell and cmd provides the content and logic. To compare it to an gui application:

```
Conhost = WinForms          -> Visual library/engine used to give form apps a common look.
Your app = Form application -> Unique logic and content
```

The console-host background is usually set with `Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;`, but this method only supports the colors in the `ConsoleColor`-enumerator.

What PowerShell does, is overwrite the standard consolecolors (you could do this manually in the properties of a console window or a shortcut too). To do this with code, you need to use a few tricks. Try this sample that I've built using code from the source below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;                // for Debug
using System.Drawing;                    // for Color (add reference to  System.Drawing.assembly)
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;    // for StructLayout

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color back = Color.FromArgb(1,36,86); //RGB retrieved from conhost properties in a powershell console
            Color text = Color.FromArgb(238, 237, 240);  //RGB retrieved from conhost properties in a powershell console
            SetScreenColorsApp.SetScreenColors(text, back);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }




    // Copyright Alex Shvedov
    // Modified by MercuryP with color specifications
    // Use this code in any way you want

    class SetScreenColorsApp
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COORD
        {
            internal short X;
            internal short Y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct SMALL_RECT
        {
            internal short Left;
            internal short Top;
            internal short Right;
            internal short Bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COLORREF
        {
            internal uint ColorDWORD;

            internal COLORREF(Color color)
            {
                ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R + (((uint)color.G) << 8) + (((uint)color.B) << 16);
            }

            internal COLORREF(uint r, uint g, uint b)
            {
                ColorDWORD = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
            }

            internal Color GetColor()
            {
                return Color.FromArgb((int)(0x000000FFU & ColorDWORD),
                                      (int)(0x0000FF00U & ColorDWORD) >> 8, (int)(0x00FF0000U & ColorDWORD) >> 16);
            }

            internal void SetColor(Color color)
            {
                ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R + (((uint)color.G) << 8) + (((uint)color.B) << 16);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX
        {
            internal int cbSize;
            internal COORD dwSize;
            internal COORD dwCursorPosition;
            internal ushort wAttributes;
            internal SMALL_RECT srWindow;
            internal COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;
            internal ushort wPopupAttributes;
            internal bool bFullscreenSupported;
            internal COLORREF black;
            internal COLORREF darkBlue;
            internal COLORREF darkGreen;
            internal COLORREF darkCyan;
            internal COLORREF darkRed;
            internal COLORREF darkMagenta;
            internal COLORREF darkYellow;
            internal COLORREF gray;
            internal COLORREF darkGray;
            internal COLORREF blue;
            internal COLORREF green;
            internal COLORREF cyan;
            internal COLORREF red;
            internal COLORREF magenta;
            internal COLORREF yellow;
            internal COLORREF white;
        }

        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;                                        // per WinBase.h
        internal static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);    // per WinBase.h

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, ref CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX csbe);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, ref CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX csbe);

        // Set a specific console color to an RGB color
        // The default console colors used are gray (foreground) and black (background)
        public static int SetColor(ConsoleColor consoleColor, Color targetColor)
        {
            return SetColor(consoleColor, targetColor.R, targetColor.G, targetColor.B);
        }

        public static int SetColor(ConsoleColor color, uint r, uint g, uint b)
        {
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX csbe = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX();
            csbe.cbSize = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(csbe);                    // 96 = 0x60
            IntPtr hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);    // 7
            if (hConsoleOutput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            bool brc = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsoleOutput, ref csbe);
            if (!brc)
            {
                return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }

            switch (color)
            {
                case ConsoleColor.Black:
                    csbe.black = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkBlue:
                    csbe.darkBlue = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkGreen:
                    csbe.darkGreen = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkCyan:
                    csbe.darkCyan = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkRed:
                    csbe.darkRed = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta:
                    csbe.darkMagenta = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkYellow:
                    csbe.darkYellow = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Gray:
                    csbe.gray = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.DarkGray:
                    csbe.darkGray = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Blue:
                    csbe.blue = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Green:
                    csbe.green = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Cyan:
                    csbe.cyan = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Red:
                    csbe.red = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Magenta:
                    csbe.magenta = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.Yellow:
                    csbe.yellow = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
                case ConsoleColor.White:
                    csbe.white = new COLORREF(r, g, b);
                    break;
            }
            ++csbe.srWindow.Bottom;
            ++csbe.srWindow.Right;
            brc = SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsoleOutput, ref csbe);
            if (!brc)
            {
                return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static int SetScreenColors(Color foregroundColor, Color backgroundColor)
        {
            int irc;
            irc = SetColor(ConsoleColor.Gray, foregroundColor);
            if (irc != 0) return irc;
            irc = SetColor(ConsoleColor.Black, backgroundColor);
            if (irc != 0) return irc;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx)